# Is it posible to create a urlManager Rule which preloads an object based on ID?

Tags: php, yii2

Working with Yii 2.0.4, I'm trying to use urlManager Rule to preload an object based on a given ID in the URL.

> config/web.php

```
'components' => [
    'urlManager' => [
        [
            'pattern' => 'view/<id:\d+>',
            'route' => 'site/view',
            'defaults' => ['client' => Client::findOne($id)],
        ],
        [
            'pattern' => 'update/<id:\d+>',
            'route' => 'site/update',
            'defaults' => ['client' => Client::findOne($id)],
        ],

    ]
]
```

If this works, it will not be necessary to manually find and object each time, for some CRUD actions:

```
class SiteController extends Controller {
    public function actionView() {
        // Using the $client from the urlManager Rule
        // Instead of using $client = Client::findOne($id);

        return $this->render('view', ['client' => $client]);
    }

    public function actionUpdate() {
        // Using $client from urlManager Rule
        // Instead of using $client = Client::findOne($id);

        if ($client->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $client->save()) {
                return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $client->id]);
            } else {
                return $this->render('edit', ['client' => $client]);
            }
    }

}
```

**NOTE:** The above snippets are not working.  They're the idea of what I want to get

Is it possible?  Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: I don't believe so. Looking at the [source](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/web/UrlRule.php#L240) `defaults` doesn't have access to matched params from the rule

Answer (score 0):

If you look closer: nothing actually changes. You still call `Client::findOne($id);` but now doing it in an unexpected and inappropriate place, and if you look at the [comment about `default` parameter](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/web/UrlRule.php#L60) it says:

> array the default GET parameters (name => value) that this rule provides.
>   When this rule is used to parse the incoming request, the values declared in this property will be injected into $_GET.

*default* parameter is needed when you want to specify some `$_GET` parameters for your rule. E.g.

```
[
    'pattern' => '/',
    'route' => 'article/view',
    'defaults' => ['id' => 1],
]
```

Here we specify article with *id* = 1 as default article when you open main page of site e.g. http://example.com/ will be handled as http://example.com/article/view?id=1

I can suggest to you add property `clientModel` in to your controller and then in `beforeAction()` method check if its *update* or *view* action then set

`$this->clientModel = Client::findOne($id);`

and in your action:

`return $this->render('view', ['client' => $this->clientModel]);`

Comment: Thank's.  I read the 'default' parameter doc before posting my question, but I was trying to explain what I wanted to achieve.  Nevertheless I appreciate your suggestion about the `beforeAction()`.  I'll try it, and post here the solution.